# how to push this modified file to github repository

Tags: git, github

how can i push this modified file in github

```
% git status
    # On branch master
    # Changed but not updated:
    #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working
    #   directory)
    #    modified:   login.php
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: Which file are you trying to push? Were you able to commit it?

Answer (score 27):

```
git status
```

It will show you all modified file and new file in working tree

```
modified:   file path
```

Untracked files: that are not tracked by Git

**For adding Untracked files**

```
git add <file path>
```

after adding file you need to commit

```
 git commit -m "< your message>"
```

**For committing only modified file**

```
git commit -m "<your message>" <file_path 1> <file_path2>
```

**Pushing code to git**

```
git push <origin> <branch_name>
```

Update remote refs along with associated objects

For more details read [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial)

Answer (score 7):

Your current status is that you performed a change in a file that git is tracking, but haven't done anything with this change. So first, you should "tell" git about this change, or stage it to be committed (note that you can stage several files/changes at once):

```
% git add login.php
```

Once that is done, you need to commit this change, and add a message explaining what this change contains:

```
% git commit -m "Fixed bug in login.php"
```

You can now proceed to push this change to github:

```
% git push origin my_branch
```